# Efficient way to save data in Redis DB

Tags: redis

In my Redis DB I want to save the following data:

```
{"id": "1", "data": "abc", "param": "p1"}
{"id": "2", "data": "def", "param": "p2"}
```

Currently I am saving each line as follows (using `Jedis` client in Java):

```
JEDIS.set(line.getId(),line.getLine());
```

So, the result is something like this:

```
"1", "{"id": "1", "data": "abc", "param": "p1"}"

GET 1
{"id": "1", "data": "abc", "param": "p1"}
```

Is it an efficient way to save this kind of data in Redis? Maybe it's better to convert each line to a `Set` or something?

Comment: Sure, it's an efficient way to *save* it. But how do you plan to *access* it? That's the most important thing in choosing the right data structure.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry: I am new to Redis, but my idea was to read Json strings from Redis by ID and then perform parsing from my code. However, I am not sure if there is any way to avoid this parsing and also to consume less memory. The problem is that now I am also consuming the extra-memory resources for saving the punctuation of Json strings (e.g. `{`, `}`, `"`).

Comment: It sounds like what you need is mongodb

Comment: @for_stack: I am forced to use Redis. In fact it's for caching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you need to do is get and set blobs of data, then a straightforward use of `GET` and `SET` makes sense. If memory use is a concern you could use MessagePack instead of JSON.

If your usual patterns of access don't involve the entire object, an alternative is to use a Hash, since that would allow you to get and set fields individually, reducing the amount of data you need to transfer. (It wouldn't reduce the total amount of memory needed to store your data, though.)

Answer (score 2):

Hashes are perfect for what you need as you can access the values of individual fields directly using HSET and HGET, and they are very memory efficient and optimised for this purpose. http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization#use-hashes-when-possible